# real analysis: combinations of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

So I'm done with half of this question but i'm unsure about the second half

Suppose $f$, $g$ : D --> R are both continuous. Prove that the function $f$∨$g$ and $f$∧$g$ defined on D by

($f$∨$g$)(x) = $f$(x)∨$g$(x) = max{$f$(x),$g$(x)}

($f$∧$g$)(x) = $f$(x)∧$g$(x) = min{$f$(x),$g$(x)}
 are continuous.  Hint: show that $f$∨$g$ = 1\2($f$+$g$+|$f-g$|) and $f$∧$g$ = 1\2($f$+$g$-|$f-g$|)

I've already proved the case for $f$∨$g$= max{$f$, $g$}, but i'm not sure about the case for min.

**Attempted solution**

|$f-g$| = $f-g$, f>g and $g-f$, f≤g

case(1): let f>g then |$f-g$|= f-g

$f$∧$g$ = min{$f$,$g$} = g

to prove that g = $f$∧$g$ = 1\2($f$+$g$-|$f-g$|)

R.H.S= 1\2($f$+$g$-|$f-g$|) = 1\2($f$+$g$-$f-g$)

and here i'm wrong. is the min of $f$∧$g$ is even g? or the values of |$f-g$| is wrong? I did this approach for the max case and it worked.

any help is appreciated

Comment: $\min\{f,g\}$ is just $-\max\{-f,-g\}$.

Comment: |$f-g$| = $f-g$ for $f>g$ and $= g-f$ for $f \le g$ is true, but neither $f > g$ nor $f \le g$ need to be satisfied.

Comment: can you tell me where was I wrong in my attempt? when I continue my approach (+-−) are cancelled together and i'm left with 1\2..

Answer (score 1):

Since$$\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\frac12\bigl(f(x)+g(x)+\bigl\lvert f(x)-g(x)\bigr\rvert\bigr)$$and $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is continuous too.

And you can prove that $\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is continuous using that fact that$$\min\{f(x),g(x)\}=\frac12\bigl(f(x)+g(x)-\bigl\lvert f(x)-g(x)\bigr\rvert\bigr).$$

Comment: Once you've shown the max is continuous you are done, see my comment to the original question.

Comment: Sure. I agree. That's a a fine answer and I wrote what I wrote because I wanted to provide another approach.

Comment: @TSF so I can say "by using the fact that the min{,} is −max{−,−} , min is also continuous"?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos just by using the fact that  and  are continuous I can prove their max and min to be continuous too? didn't think of that approach, thank you

Comment: @raydiiii You're welcome.